# how to trim the characters in an path extracted from XML?

Tags: java, xml

```
//abc:def/m1/m/123/test
```

Im extracting the path from an xml file .
I want to trim the characters `"/test"`(remove these characters from path). have tried with `lastIndexOf(".") and trim().` Unable to trim the characters .

Comment: tell us the output you are expecting ?

Comment: im expecting the output //abc:def/m1/m/123

Answer (score 2):

if you want to _remove `/text`, you can try

```
String path="//abc:def/m1/m/123/test";
path = path.substring(0,path.lastIndexOf("/"));
System.out.println(path);
```

Output:

```
//abc:def/m1/m/123
```

Comment: simpleXpath=arrSimpleXpath.get(i).toString();
     simpleXpath=simpleXpath.substring(0, simpleXpath.lastIndexOf("/")); im fetching the path from xml through simpleXpath tried but not working...

Comment: @user3769879 are you sure the value of `simpleXpath` is `//abc:def/m1/m/123/test`?

Comment: what value did you get after `substring`? is it still the same?

Comment: yes it is still the same it is not removing /test after substring and lastindexof

Comment: are you really2 sure its `//abc:def/m1/m/123/test` not `//abc:def/m1/m/123/test/`? if yes, then you may try @ TAsk's solution below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substring` and `indexOf` As you specifically want to remove `String` from  `/test`

```
String str="//abc:def/m1/m/123/test";
System.out.println(str.substring(0, str.indexOf("/test")));
```

---

*NOTE*

If you have `String` like `//abc:def/m1/m/123/test/other/extra` than it will remove `String` after `/test` also. So if you want to remove *last element* of path I suggest you to go for `lastIndexOf('/')`.

<sub>(*As `Immer Allein` has already suggested*)</sub>

---

If you want to remove `/test` you can also do it like this if you have more elements in path after `/test`. (i.e `//abc:def/m1/m/123/test/other/extra`)

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
sb.append(str.substring(0, str.indexOf("/test")));
sb.append(str.substring(str.indexOf("/test")+5));
System.out.println(sb);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
//abc:def/m1/m/123/other/extra
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
   String s = new String("//abc:def/m1/m/123/test" );
 System.out.println(""+s.substring(0,s.lastIndexOf("/")));
```